# Kubernetes Operator Wide Objects and Instance Wide Objects

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am writing Kubernetes operator in golang and I am new to golang. I have few questions based on best practices:

1. The operator I am building can serve multiple instances of my application
2. Each application instance is independent of each other
3. Application is mostly stateful

   ```
   type myApp struct {
            name  string
     }

    // MyAppReconciler reconciles a MyApp object
    type MyAppReconciler struct {
            client.Client
            Log               logr.Logger
            Scheme            *runtime.Scheme
            kubeClient        kubernetes.Interface
            kubeConfig        clientcmd.ClientConfig
            instance          *appV1.MyApp
            addNewApp        []myApp
            addSHState        bool
            addSemAcuireMsg   string
    }

    // ConfigurationProvider wraps information about the account owner

    var myAppSem = semaphore.NewWeighted(1)
    var App1Sem = semaphore.NewWeighted(1)
   ```

If I declare a global variables like myAppSem, they become operator wise resource i.e. all my App instances ( like app1 inst, appnst2 CR ) access the same semaphores. Also, assign values to MyAppReconciler such as addNewApp then these values are available to all the same CR so technically if I run multiple app instances then operator mess up the env.

Is there a way to declare and define the struct which is at per CR resource. If I declare struct under following then I need to pass the struct to all the functions but I want in that app instance it must maintains its copy and each CR must have its own copy.

```
func (r *MyAppReconciler) Reconcile(req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
        // _ = context.Background()
        _ = r.Log.WithValues("Instance.Namespace", req.NamespacedName)

        // your logic here


}
```

Comment: What information are you trying to keep there?  In general, I believe your controller must be stateless (like other Pods, it can be destroyed and recreated with no warning to you) but you can put information into the other objects you manage (annotations, custom resources' status blocks, _etc._).

Comment: I have stateful pods and I keep a track of record update/delete using semaphores and some app-related info in the struct.